# PHP datetime add 6 months and 1 year

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date set using PHP datetime like this..

```
$originaldate = 2019-01-10 17:52:17
$converted = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $originaldate);
```

The date is successfuly converted into a PHP DateTime object, now I am trying to add create 2 new dates that are 6 months and 1 year ahead of this date.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you can try play around with Carbon. carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ It is very useful and human readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look into php class *DateInterval* http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Here's an example:

```
$converted = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $originaldate); 
$converted1Year = $converted->add(new DateInterval("P1Y"));//add one year //object reference is the same so adding a year altered original object and a reference to it is passed back, not copied
$converted2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $originaldate);
$converted6months = $converted2->add(new DateInterval("P6M")); // add 6 months
```

And as suggested in the comments here's the *DateTimeImmutable* equivalent:

```
$converted = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $originaldate); 
$converted1Year = $converted->add(new DateInterval("P1Y"));
$converted6Months = $converted->add(new DateInterval("P6M"));
```

Comment: This doesn't work - note that each call to `add` modifies `$converted` and returns it, rather than just returning a new object. So `$sixmonthsahead` is actually 18 months ahead, as the object has already had a year added to it. If you use `DateTimeImmutable` instead, you can avoid this problem.

Comment: @user3647971: you could find better solution than initiating twice the same object. For example you could use `DateTimeImmutable` class.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`DateTime::add`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
$converted->add(new DateInterval("P18M")); // add 18 months
```

`P18M` means 18 month interval

Answer (score 3):

You can [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the time to create a duplicate and use [DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to change the new date.

Try this;

```
$sixMonths = clone $converted;
$sixMonths->modify('+6 months');

$oneYear = clone $converted;
$oneYear->modify('+1 year');
```

Comment: Is this PHP?
http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=clone&scope=quickref

Comment: @DeniseMeander Yes `clone` is part [`PHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: Does this method offer anything over using DateTime::add?

Comment: @fightstarr20 `DateTime::modify` takes a human-readable string, `DateTime::add` takes a `DateInterval` object, which uses ISO-8601 format strings. Completely up to you which you prefer though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$converted = $converted->modify('+6 months');
$converted = $converted->modify('+1 year');
```

Comment: This advice was given ~4 hours earlier by Memduh.  This unexplained answer adds no new value to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
   $sixMonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($converted. ' + 6 months'));
   $oneYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($converted. ' + 1 year'));
```

Comment: This won't work if `$converted` is a `DateTime` object, will it?

Comment: Giving answers based on simple unix-timestamp-based functions like date() and strtotime() is rarely good advice when the person raising the question has already moved on to using more sophisticated DateTime objects

Answer (score 0):

The format already default **("Y-m-d H:i:s")**. You don't need to use CreateFromFormat, unless you are handle data from 3rd party. My suggestion for the code would be like this

```
$originaldate = '2019-01-10 17:52:17';
$converted = new DateTime( $originaldate ); //prefer like this
//DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $originaldate); //after browsing this is recomended

$date6Month = new DateTime( $originaldate );
$date1Year = new DateTime( $originaldate );
$dateBack = new DateTime( $originaldate );
//$date6Month = $date1Year = $dateBack= $converted;
//prefer to use different variable for every date. Not copy

echo "ori:".$converted ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n"; 
//ori:2019-01-10 17:52:17

##6 month later
$date6Month ->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo "6 month:".$date6Month ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
//6 month:2019-07-10 17:52:17

##1 year later
$date1Year ->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
echo "1 year:".$date1Year ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
//1 year:2020-01-10 17:52:17
//1 year:2020-07-10 17:52:17 (wrong if using copy main parameter)

$date1Year ->add(  DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 Years') );
echo "1 year (later):".$date1Year ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
//1 year (later):2021-01-10 17:52:17
//1 year (later):2021-07-10 17:52:17 (wrong if using copy main parameter)
```

you can use DateInterval::createFromDateString for readable code than using format. My suggestion is to separated the variable not copy from the origin.

The format you can use on DateInterval

Start "P" when contain Day, Month and Year

| Format | Info | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y | Year | 1Y |
| M | Month | 3M |
| D | Day | 5D |

example: **P1Y3M5D**

Always Start "P" before "T" if not contain Day, Month and Year (PT1H). If not start it with "T"

| Format | Info | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| H | HOUR | 1H |
| M | MINUTES | 3M |
| S | SECONDS | 5S |
| F | MICROSECOND (php7+) | 5F |

example: **PT1H3M5S**

wrong: *T1H3M5S*

other example (from link below)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix'); 
//is important to add when your time are detail
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7Y5M4DT4H3M2S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
//2007-06-05 04:03:02

$originaldate = 2019-01-10 17:52:17
$dateBack = $dateBack2 = new DateTime( $originaldate );
//if you want to substract the value you can use this
$dateBack ->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y2M3DT1H4M1S'));
echo $dateBack ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
//output: 2019-05-07 16:48:16

$dateBack2=$converted;
$formatDay='P1Y3M6D'; //only year, month and day 
$formatTime='T1H3M6S'; //only hour, minutes and seconds
$dateBack2 ->sub(new DateInterval( $formatDay.$formatTime ));
echo $dateBack ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
//2018-02-01 15:45:10
```

as mention on the phpmanual, there is other format (microtime) that's not include on this example.

related link

- [Date Time PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)
- [Date Interval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
- [Format on Interval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)
- [Date Interval create using String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php)